# Show jQuery slider on HTML page when html request came from computer , hide it when request came from mobile device?

Tags: jquery-ui, mobile-website

Is there a way to show  the slider when a computer access the page and hide it and to instead select display when mobile device (iphone) access throught mobile-safari?

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect the device that you will be using. This link about [detecting smartphone using javascript](http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-javascript.htm) may be helpful.

However, it would have been better if you do this by server side scripting.